# Scrollers are not displaying in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, scroller

I have a span inside a div, and although I can scroll vertically just fine, there are no scroll indicators displayed like I'd usually see in a UIWebView while scrolling.  Any clues to why?

This is formulated in javascript

```
    $(".contentArea").append('<div style="width=300px; height:520px; 
overflow-x:visible; overflow-y: scroll; position: relative; top: 0px; 
left: 15px;"><span class="description">' + $(this).find("Description").text() 
+ '</span></div>');
```

CSS:

```
#contentArea{
    position:relative;
    width:600px;
    height:768px;
    font-size: 13px; 
    line-height:20px;
}

span.description {
    line-height:17px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the scroll view inside the UIWebView and set it to display bars:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = nil;
for (UIView *subview in webview.subviews) 
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) 
        scrollView = (UIScrollView *)scrollView;

scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
```

Comment: Adding this has no effect. It is in my viewDidLoad below my webview's loadRequest.